# Solving $x'=Ax$ for 2x2 matrix with repeated eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the general solution to the system $x' = Ax$. Here,

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -3\\
3 & -5
\end{pmatrix} $$

Finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, I found the eigenvalue of $-2$ to correspond to the eigenvector $  \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} $

I am confused about how to proceed to finding the final solution here. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to compute $e^{At}$?

Comment: Since the matrix is defective, you need a generalized eigenvector. Once you have both, you need to find the Jordan form, which basically says how $A$ acts on its one true eigenvector (multiplies it by $-2$) and how it acts on the generalized eigenvector (which will be to multiply it by $-2$ and then add the other eigenvector). Then finally you need to figure out the matrix exponential of the Jordan form, which is not *quite* as easy as in the diagonal case, but not that bad.

Comment: @copper.hat I am trying to figure out the additional term, but trial and error hasn't gotten me anywhere so far.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ian! That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @pinkUnicorn999 As with scalar ODEs with repeated roots, the general solution will involve $e^{-2t}$ and $t e^{-2t}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yup, your hint helped me find the form of $c_2e^{λ\:t}\left(tη+ρ\right)$ for the additional term. So the general form looks to be $c_1e^{λ\:t} + c_2e^{λ\:t}\left(tη+ρ\right)$. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @pinkUnicorn999 It is related to the generalised eigenvector that Moo mentions below. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a deficient matrix and need to find a [*generalized eigenvector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).

You have a double eigenvalue of $\lambda_{1,2} = -2$.

Solve for $v_2$ using the row-reduced-echelon-form (RREF) of $$[A-\lambda I]v_2 = [A + 2I]v_2 = v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Spoiler

> $$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{3} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Aha I got the solution now, thank you so much!