# Solving a nonhomogenous system of eqns with one eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fundamental-solution

I have the system:

$\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x' \\
           y'
    \end{array} \right]= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    3&2 \\
    -2 & -1 
    \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x' \\
           y'
    \end{array} \right]+\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    2e^{-t} \\
          e^{-t}
    \end{array} \right]$

Which I should solve using the fundamental matrix.

So I start with obtaining the homogenous solution:

I find the eigenvalues;
\begin{pmatrix}
    3-\lambda&2 \\
    -2 & -1-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}

which gives the determinant: $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$. Thus $\lambda_1=1$. Plugging that in the matrix in the original equation, I get that x=y. So a solution to the homogenous system would be: $y_h=e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    1 \\
          1
    \end{array} \right]$

Since there is no second solution to the determinant, I would ideally form the fundamental matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{t} & e^0 \\
    e^{t} & e^0 
\end{pmatrix}

but this is to no avail. So how do I find the solution of this nonhomogenous system using the fundamental matrix with one eigenvalue?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I set up the generalized eigenvector formula
\begin{equation}
v_2(A-\lambda I)=v_2
\begin{pmatrix}
     3-\lambda&2 \\
    -2 & -1-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}=v_1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
v_2(A-\lambda I)=v_1=
\begin{vmatrix}
     3-\lambda&2 & | 1 \\
    -2 & -1-\lambda & |-1  
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

I now get as given by Moo, with Gaussian elimination, the matrix:

\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
     1 &1 & | 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & |0  
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

and have the second eigenvector: $e_2=e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \frac{1}{2} \\
          0
    \end{array} \right]$
.

So the homogeneous solution is:

\begin{equation}
y_h=e^{\lambda_1 t}e_1+e^{\lambda_2t}e_2=e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    1 \\
          -1
    \end{array} \right]+e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \frac{1}{2} \\
          0
    \end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

At this stage, it remains to find the particular solution. We know that it must be in the form of:

\begin{equation}
y_p=Ce^{-t}
\end{equation}

and thus the general solution is:

\begin{equation}
y_p=y_h+Ce^{-t}=e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    1 \\
          -1
    \end{array} \right]+e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \frac{1}{2} \\
          0
    \end{array} \right]+Ce^{-t}
\end{equation}

But can this be said?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @Moo I tried this, and find the eigenvector to be a matrix rather than a vector. So it would be $v_2=v_1(A+2I)^{-1}$. In the case here, where $v_1=(1,1)$. I get that $v_2=(1/5  -4/5) \overset{(0  5)} $

Comment: The reason I pointed to those notes is that this is different because of the deficient matrix. You should get https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%27+%3D+3x+%2B+2+y+%2B+2+e%5E%28-t%29%2C+y%27+%3D+-2+x+-+y+%2B+e%5E%28-t%29%7D. I would strongly recommend spending time in the notes link below. Regards

Comment: So the inhomogenous solution is not solvable here, only the homogenous solution is found?

Comment: Yes, it is solvable. I think you need to go through examples and work them, otherwise, you will continue to struggle with them. Seek out many example on MSE and the we and go through them and make sure you can do them. My 2 cents. Note, the Wolfram Alpha link shows $$y = y_h + y_p$$ and you need to work out the details or post another question for that. Regards

Comment: Will have a look at this next week! Thanks Moo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what is called a [*deficient matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), so you need to find a [*generalized eigenvector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).

We have the system

$$\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x' \\
           y'
    \end{array} \right]= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    3&2 \\
    -2 & -1 
    \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x \\
           y
    \end{array} \right]+\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    2e^{-t} \\
          e^{-t}
    \end{array} \right]$$

We find a repeated eigenvalue of $\lambda_{1,2} = 1$ and we can find a single eigenvector of

$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Finding generalized eigenvectors is not a simple topic and requires work to learn the ins and outs, but in this case, we will use this [*example*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126332/solving-x-ax-for-2x2-matrix-with-repeated-eigenvalues).

Solve for $v_2$ using the row-reduced-echelon-form (RREF) of $[A-\lambda I]v_2 = [A -I]v_2 = v_1 $

We get the augmented matrix

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

We can choose

$$v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Update** For the eigenvalues, we find

$$|A - \lambda I| = \begin{vmatrix}
 -\lambda +3 & 2 \\
 -2 & -\lambda -1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = (-\lambda+3)(-\lambda - 1) -2(-2) = \lambda ^2-2 \lambda +1 = 0$$

This results in

$$\lambda_{1, 2} = 1$$

To find the generalized eigenvector, we solve (you are actually using the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ below)

$$[A - \lambda I]v_2 = [A - 1 I]v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 2 \\
 -2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}v_2 = v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

That is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 2 \\
 -2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As an augmented matrix, this is

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    2 & 2 & -1 \\ -2 & -2 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

The RREF (Gaussian Elimination) is

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

From this, we can choose

$$v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Now I see!

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: You can, for example, see these notes http://math.ucsd.edu/~aterras/matrix%20exp%20etc.pdf

Comment: Will take this further tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Moo, I found a mistake in my oiginal post, there us a change in the eigenvalue, and in the eigenvector. It makes the system even more elusive. $y_h=e^{t}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    0 \\
          0
    \end{array} \right]$

Comment: So what is wrong here? $\lambda=-1$

Comment: Yes, I recall. But I made a mistake in the original calculation of the determinant, and now the eigenvalue is not 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132405/discussion-between-viola-player-and-moo).

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283-x%29%28-x-1%29

Comment: You're right, I typed in the wrong equation. But can you outline how you get that matrix? Thanks, I will use your procedure here. All the best

Comment: Attempt added, but I don't see how you get that augmented matrix with two 1's, two 0's

Comment: Thanks, it is very clear now. I will write this on paper.

Comment: check out this new post, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355749/solving-an-inhomogenous-system-of-equations-with-one-eigenvalue