# Solving an inhomogenous system of equations with one eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, having the system, which was investigated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335192/solving-a-nonhomogenous-system-of-eqns-with-one-eigenvalue?noredirect=1) post:

$\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x' \\
           y'
    \end{array} \right]= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    3&2 \\
    -2 & -1 
    \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x' \\
           y'
    \end{array} \right]+\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    2e^{-t} \\
          e^{-t}
    \end{array} \right]$

but where the particular solutions where not included, I prepare a full outline of this solution.

**PART ONE: FIND THE **HOMOGENOUS SOLUTION.****

1. Find the eigenvalue(s):

\begin{pmatrix}
    3-\lambda&2 \\
    -2 & -1-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}

yielding: $\lambda=1$.

2. Find the eigenvector:

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
    3-1 &2\\
    -2 & -1-1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Solve the inherent equation, either of the two:

\begin{equation}
2x+2y=0 \rightarrow x=-y \longrightarrow e_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Since we have only one eigenvalue, we need to construct the second, generalized, eigenvector.

3. Construction of generalized eigenvector.

Use the formula: $(A)e_2=e_1$ $\rightarrow$ $e_2=(A)^{-1}e_1$

Find the inverse of $A$:

\begin{equation}
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{2\cdot2-(-2)\cdot2}
\begin{pmatrix}
   -3 &-2\\
    2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

which gives:

\begin{equation}
A^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{3}{2} &1\\
    -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

prepare the formula $e_2=(A)^{-1}e_1$:

\begin{equation}
e_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{3}{2} &1\\
    -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Do a matrix row-reduction

\begin{equation}
e_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{2} &0\\
    -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The eigenvector $e_2$ is according to the proposed solution by Moo in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335192/solving-a-nonhomogenous-system-of-eqns-with-one-eigenvalue?noredirect=1) the last column:

\begin{equation}
e_2=\begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

We have the homogenous solution $y_h=c_1e^{\lambda t}e_1+c_2e^{\lambda t}e_2$:

\begin{equation}
y_h=c_1e^{t}\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{t}\begin{pmatrix}
    0\\ 
    -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

**PART TWO: FIND THE PARTICULAR SOLUTION**

The steps to find a particular solution for the system at hand, are the following:

1. Create a eigenvector matrix, T, and its inverse $T^{-1}$.
2. Create an eigenvalue matrix, B.
3. Set up the formula, with a new variable, $z$ and the nonhomogenous part from the original system at the top:
   \begin{equation}
    z'=Bz+T^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}2e^{-t} \\
             e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}
   \end{equation}

We have:

\begin{equation}
T=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}, \ \ T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&-1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

(Note that B is NOT the identity matrix, it is just for this case that with $\lambda=1$, we get the identity matrix out of B.)

Prepare the new system:

\begin{equation}
z^{\prime}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&-1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}z+\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2e^{-t}\\
e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
this gives two equations to be solved individually:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fz'=z-3e^{-t}\\
z'=z+e^{-t}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

**PART THREE SOLVE THE EQUATIONS**

The two equations are solved easily by integrating factor method:

\begin{equation}
z_1'=z_1-3e^{-t} \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\big[e^{-t}z_1\big]=-3e^{-t}\cdot e^{-t} \rightarrow e^{-t}z_1=-3\int e^{-2t} dt\rightarrow z_{p_1}=\frac{3}{2}e^{-t}+ce^{-t}
\end{equation}

and for the second equation:

\begin{equation}
z_2'=z_2+e^{-t} \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\big[e^{-t}z_2\big]=e^{-t}\cdot e^{-t} \rightarrow e^{-t}z_2=-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-2t}+c dt \rightarrow z_{p_2}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+ce^{-t}
\end{equation}

**PART FOUR, FORM THE FINAL SOLUTION**

The final solution is formed by the equation $X(t)=T\begin{pmatrix}
z_1\\
z_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Inserting for T and $z_1$ and $z_2$ we obtain:

\begin{equation}
X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}+c\bigg)\\
e^{-t}\bigg(c-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Since this is a big example, please comment if you find any errors.

Editors: Please add a new tag: "NONHOMOGENOUS" for this post, and also for future similar posts.

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused. In the post, the eigenvectors are $v_1 = (-1, 1)^T, v_2 = (-1/2, 0)^T$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is incorrect. For a planar system with a repeated eigenvalue, the homogeneous solution is $\mathbf{x}(t) = (c_1 + c_2t)e^{\lambda t}\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2e^{\lambda t}\mathbf{v}_2$, where $\mathbf{v}_1$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ a generalised eigenvector.